# Facebook in online accounts

Tags: facebook, online-accounts

I have g-mail configured in online accounts. But when trying to add other accounts, such as Facebook and Linkedin, I am not able to do so, since the account type I am able to select is only google. Is there a way to add Facebook account type to online accounts? If yes, can you please guide me to the proper steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the online accounts dialog is only a shortcut, meant to configure many applications at once. Facebook is supported in two ways in Ubuntu by default; as a social network and as a chat service. To setup the social networking part, you'll open Broadcasting from the messaging menu (the one with an envelope). It will ask you to enter details for the various networks, including Facebook. To configure instant messaging, open Instant Messaging from the messaging menu. It will also ask for account details. Afterwards, you'll have both Gmail and Facebook chat in Empathy. You can also ask to be notified when users log on and off, which means when they open Facebook or Gmail in their browsers, or when they start Empathy if they've set it up like you. You do that in Edit > Preferences in Empathy.